# How can I match the second occurrence of a character with a regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match the second forward-slash in a relative URL.

```
/dir/entry
```

I want to match the `/` following `dir`.

Comment: which language?what have u tried?what do you actually want to match?

Comment: I'm using a plugin for a PHP-powered CMS.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to break apart the directories in the path, it probably makes sense to leave the regexes in the toolbox and use `explode()`.

```
$parts = explode( '/', $path );
```

Comment: If you also pass a `$limit` of `3`, `$parts[2]` will contain everything after the second `/`.

Comment: yeah, i was trying to avoid writing an add-on or any php by using an existing one that finds via regex and replaces w/o regex. also, i need to return the second `/`, not use them as delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no significance about the `/`, I assume you want to find out the position. You can do it with the fourth parameter of `preg_match_all`:

```
preg_match_all('~/~', $input, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$pos = $matches[0][1][1];
```

The indexing into `$matches` is quite horrible, though. The first index corresponds to the capture. `0` is the whole match, `1`, `2`, `3` and so on would be the results of capturing groups (sets of parentheses inside the pattern), which you don't have here. The second index corresponds to the match. You want the second match, so you want to go for index `1`. The last index is `0` for the actually matched/captured string and `1` for the match's/capture's offset.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to match the second slash and nothing else?  Try this:

```
preg_match('~^/[^/]+\K/~', '/dir/entry');
```

`\K` is the `MATCH POINT RESET` construct: when it's encountered, the regex engine "forgets" whatever characters it's seen so far, and acts like the current match position is the beginning of the match.  For example, if you wanted to replace the second slash with `@`, you would normally do this:

```
preg_replace('~^(/[^/]+)/~', '$1@', '/dir/entry');  # /dir@entry
```

But if you're in a situation where you can't use a capturing group, `\K` will set you right:

```
preg_replace('~^/[^/]+\K/~', '@', '/dir/entry');  # /dir@entry
```

`\K` is only supported in Perl and PHP that I know of.